# CA0053 unable to load rule assembly dataflowrules.dll VS 2017

Tags: .net, ide, visual-studio-2017

All of a sudden, I am getting this error when I am trying to build my project - 
[image]

I recetnly upgraded to Visual Studio 2017 from 2015.
I saw some answers where they have suggested to update csproj or solution file but it is not working.

Please help. I can't think any further.

Comment: It is trying to use VS2015 rules, that is not going to work.  Your project is probably broken, open the .csproj file in a text editor like Notepad and look for an invalid CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories element.  Delete it if you see it.

Comment: Great! It is working! Till now I was trying to change the path mentioned inside CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories. It didn't occur to me to delete it. Thanks for the help!!